# Devise.friendly_token returns an equal hash all the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random, devise, auth-token, http-token-authentication

I am all mixed up trying to understand what happens here:
I use `Devise.friendly_token` in a `User` factory.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email "user@example.com"
    password "secret"
    authentication_token Devise.friendly_token
  end
end
```

In some tests I use the factory as follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SessionsController do

  before do
    @user = User.gen!
    puts "Token = #{@user.authentication_token}" # <--- debugging output
  end

  describe "#create" do
    context "when sending ..." do
      it "renders a json hash ..." do
        api_sign_in @user
        expect(last_response.status).to eq(201)
      end
    end

    context "when sending ..." do
      it "renders a json hash ..." do
        user = User.gen!(email: "invalid@email.com")
        puts "Token2 = #{user.authentication_token}" # <--- debugging output
        api_sign_in user
        expect(last_response.status).to eq(422)
      end
    end
  end

  describe "#destroy" do
    context "when sending ..." do
      it "renders a json hash ..." do
        api_sign_out @user
        expect(last_response.status).to eq(200)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

The debugging output shows that the token is the **same hash** on every call.
Strange! When I test `Devise.friendly_token` in the console it generates a **random hash** on every execution. That's what I expect looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.0.2/lib/devise.rb#L453).

I guess there is a major design problem ... Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
authentication_token Devise.friendly_token
```

will call `Devise.friendly_token` only once when the factory is initialized. You want

```
authentication_token { Devise.friendly_token }
```

which will evaluate the block every time an object is created by FactoryGirl.

Comment: Thanks again, it works fine in the specs. How comes I do not have to do this when I use `Devise.friendly_token` in my `User` model?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How do you use `Devise.friendly_token` in the `User` model?